# How to hook wm_messages with SetWindowsHookEx

Tags: c++, hook

I'm `trying` to learn about hooking, I write this code, but I'm not getting any output when the window is activated.

Also, how does SetWindowsHookEx hook works, if for example I 'intercept' the `WM_ACTIVATEAPP` and return `0`, then the window wouldn't be activated?

```
    HHOOK hhook; 
    HINSTANCE hMod;

    extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK HookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
       CWPSTRUCT cwp = *(CWPSTRUCT *)lParam;
       OutputDebugString(L"HookProc!");

       if (cwp.message == WM_ACTIVATEAPP)
       {
          OutputDebugString(L"WM_COMMAND!");
       }
    
       if (cwp.message == WM_COMMAND)
       {
          OutputDebugString(L"WM_COMMAND!");
       }
       return CallNextHookEx(nullptr, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
    
    
    void Hook(DWORD  PID)
    {
        HWND hwnd = GetWindowHWND_FromProcessId(PID);
        DWORD dwThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &PID);
        
        hMod    = LoadLibrary(L"mydll.dll");
        hhook   = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, &HookProc, hMod,  dwThreadId);

        WCHAR wsText[255] = L"";
        wsprintf(wsText, L"hkprc: %p hMod: %p dwThreadId: %d", hkprc, hMod, dwThreadId);
        OutputDebugString(wsText);
    }
```

`hhook` and `hMod` return a handle, but I'm ain't getting any output message..

Comment: A CWP hook callback must exist in a DLL, so that it can be injected into the target process.  The third argument to SetWindowsHookEx must be the module handle of that DLL.  Don't forget to check for errors.  You'd only see the output when you attach a debugger to that process.

Comment: @HansPassant Hello, the code above is inside of a DLL, also there's a debugger, about `the module handle of that dll` i dont understand this part.

Comment: @D2rake If this code is inside of a DLL, you can get the DLL's module handle from the 1st parameter of its [`DllMain()`/`DllEntryPoint()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dllmain) function. You have to tell `SetWindowsHookEx()` which instance of your DLL the hook resides in, so it knows which DLL to inject into other processes. That is what the 3rd parameter of `SetWindowsHookEx()` is meant for. Also, note that a 32bit DLL can't hook 64bit processes, and vice versa, so you will need to install separate 32bit/64bit hooks on a 64bit OS.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you, I figured how to get the module handle, however when I try to call `(HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress` its returning `000000000`.

Comment: @D2rake double check the name mangling of the exported function, it might be exported like `"_HookProc"` or `"HookProc@12"` instead. But you don't need to call `GetProcAddress()` at all if you call `SetWindowsHookEx()` inside the same DLL that implements the exported function. Just use `&HookProc` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau calling `hhook = SetWindowsHookExW(WH_CALLWNDPROC, &HookProc, hMod,  dwThreadId);` `hhook` now is returning a value, but i still dont get any output from the hook function, i have updated the post with the current code I'm using.

Comment: @D2rake there is no reason to call `LoadLibrary()` from inside the DLL that implements the hook. But in any case, how are you trying to view the output? A `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook runs in the context of the thread it is hooking, so your code shown would be calling `OutputDebugString()` from within another process. To see that output, you would need to use a tool like [SysInternals DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview), if you are not already.

Comment: @RemyLebeau im already using DebugView. `there is no reason to call LoadLibrary() from inside the DLL` what would be the third parameter of `SetWindowsHookEx` then?

Comment: @D2rake "*what would be the third parameter of `SetWindowsHookEx` then?*" - I already answered that in my very first comment yesterday: "*If this code is inside of a DLL, **you can get the DLL's module handle from the 1st parameter of its `DllMain()`/`DllEntryPoint()` function**.*"